# Move a popup window using setInterval() in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a window pops up and then moves continuously using setInterval(). It pops up but it doesn't move.
I'm using all the html files in the same directory.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>popup</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <input type="button" name="" value="new window" onclick="newWin();">
    <input type="button" name="" value="stop window" onclick="stopWin()">

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var win1;
    var interv;

    function moveWin(){
      win1.moveBy(100, 100);
      win1.focus();
    }

    function newWin(){
      win1 = window.open('new.html', 'win1', 'width=200, height=150');
      win1.focus();
      interv = setInterval(moveWin, 1000);
    }

    function stopWin(){
      clearInterval(interv);
    }


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Witch Browsers do you use for your test?

Comment: I'm using google Chrome